# SpriteBuilder | Cocos2d - Swift | XCode | ccPhysicsCollisionBegin

Tags: swift, game-physics, spritebuilder

A particular SpriteBuilder app I am developing utilises SpriteBuilder SB version 1.4.7, X Code 6.2 with iOS 8.2 iPhone deployment and func

```
ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(pair: ...) -> Bool { return true }.
```

The app runs perfectly on the iPhone 5S and iPhone 6 simulators but terminates at the above function when I use an iPhone 5, iPhone 4S or iPad 2 simulator and also when I try to load it on my 5th generation iTouch.

The error message I get is

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' reason: 'CCPhysicsCollisionBegin
>   delegate methods must return a BOOL.'

Can anyone advise me why this might be?

Comment: I'm confused about the case of `cc` and `CC` in that method.  Also as this is a swift question, please tag it with the `swift` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can also call the function and return an ObjCBool instead.
For example:
`ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(pair: ...) -> ObjCBool{ return true }`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and I found some hotfix for this to change in the Cocos Code. Seems it's a bug in CCPhysicsNode.m due to the differences between Objective-C (BOOL) and Swift (Bool). Until they fix the bug, replace the condition with:

```
NSAssert((strcmp(returnType, @encode(BOOL)) == 0 || strcmp(returnType, "B") == 0), @"CCPhysicsCollisionBegin delegate methods must return a BOOL.");
```

Hope this helps someone.